# Why Does An Account With A Poor Password Gets Hacked?

Tags: security, passwords

Whenever I choose a password, they say get a strong one, or hackers will easily get access to it.

Why?

Previously I used to believe that hackers may make a robot/software that tries many many possible combinations of passwords per second and a hard password may make the process a bit lengthy and add an extra layer of security. But as I see now that popular sites don't allow more than five or ten login trials, also they do some verification if you are logging in from another place. Then what makes hackers to successfully get access to our password if it is a poor one (like only alphabet, or only numbers).

(Is this a wrong place to ask such questions?)

Comment: Brute force can be done both on- and offline against the database. For an overview: http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/10/password-hashing-in-php-talk.html

Comment: To this day, most non-financial websites are still rather lax on security and don't do anything to mitigate automated attacks. So, the biggest problem is when you use the same password and user id (email address) on your financial sites as you do on other sites. They can automate the attack against the easy site and then easily access the other one.

Comment: O yes, I forgot to ask about that, thanks.

Comment: @AbhishekVerma - Some time ago i wrote a [tutorial](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php) about safely storing passwords, maybe you could be interested.

Comment: @Marcus - you have not seen US Financial. There's a reason US banks suffer fraud at 600x to 800x compared to their European counterparts.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is rather off-topic for SO.

If your password is very easy to guess (eg "password" or "1234"), then even the online attack you describe is quite feasible. But the primary threat to weak passwords is an [offline attack](http://www.darkreading.com/hacked-off/how-hackers-will-crack-your-password/227700892). This is where an attacker [gains access to a password database](http://www.zdnet.com/find-out-if-your-data-was-leaked-in-the-adobe-hack-7000023065/). In this situation, attacks are limited only by the attacker's resources.

Let's say you choose a completely random password of length 8 characters taken from the standard 96 characters. Some people would say that's not even a weak password. So how long will it take a knowledgeable attacker to find that password with an offline attack. [Less than 6 hours](http://arstechnica.com/security/2012/12/25-gpu-cluster-cracks-every-standard-windows-password-in-6-hours/)!

Computationally-intensive approaches such as [PKDBF2, bycrypt, and scrypt](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords?lq=1) can slow down these offline attacks by a considerable factor. But nothing will help you if your password really is weak (eg a dictionary word or two).

Having said all that, the vast majority of end-users quite rationally believe that:

- The chance of their account being compromised by a direct online attack is low.
- The chance of their account being compromised by a direct offline attack is very low.
- The bank or other organisation will likely make good any financial losses resulting from a direct offline/online compromise.

Given the above three facts, you can argue that it doesn't make sense to spend much time choosing strong passwords.

Comment: Now I understood why is it necessary, thanks. Btw some of your highly technical terms blew my mind ;)

Comment: Actually i mostly agree with your answer, but "the users believe that…" => "given the three facts…" is a bit daring, don't you think? The problem is not only for sites like a bank, often users reuse their passwords on several sites, so a low-security site can compromise a high-security site (multi target). On the other hand a slow key derivation function (BCrypt) can make it actually impossible to brute-force a strong password.

Answer (score 0):

You never know how safe a given web application is when you register. So you have to do everything you can to make you're account as safe as possible. Often, setting your password is the only thing you can do (but it's always *a* thing you can do) to increase the security. That's why you have to do it.

It's a good habit to choose strong passwords: it always increases the security of your account. Even when it's a tiny bit.

Answer (score -1):

Hackers tried simple passwords first, such as 12345678.
So if you set a simple password, it is likely that hackers guess the correct password within trial limit.

It is also possible that hackers see the message packet sent to server, which could contains password's hash value (mostly, MD5).

With this MD5 value, hackers can use brute-force or hash-collision to get a working original password string to get access to user account.

For example, a user sets 12345678 as password, hackers can run a brute-force crack within 10^8 trials to get the password (10 digit, 8 bytes length), but for password like W~9cE_f8 it is a lot difficult to crack (it needs much more trials, approx 70^8 (26 characters, upper-case + lower-case, special symbols, digits, etc), this takes a lot of time, which makes the account less profitable to the hackers,  therefore a stronger password may make account safer.

Above is just a brief explanation. Information Security related topic hardly has exact and clear answers. It is also impossible to ensure 100% safety.

Comment: MD5 has nothing to do with password hashing. That is nobody in their right mind would. Also I find "Information Security related topic hardly has exact and clear answers." very hard to believe.

Comment: Such like password security is not as safe as people usually believe, there is always debate over which way is the safest. Lots of problems have to be concerned, including psychological problem and algorithm problem, etc.

Comment: There may be debate whether scrypt is ready to be included in project X or whether the NSA has weakened algo Y, but there is no debate whether you should use MD% for hashing passwords.

Comment: MD% is just an example, it does not mean anyone should prefer using it.

Comment: MD5 is just ways too fast ([8 Giga](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat-lite/#performance) hashes per second), that's why it shouldn't be used. Then you wrote that the hash can be intercepted, but hashing is a server-side thing, you do not send a hash to the server.